# how do i fix error in java version coding "java_home: option requires an argument -- v"?

Tags: java, macos, terminal

Recently I downloaded Java SE 8 as Java SE 14 was causing me some issues on my mac. I had downloaded it and tried to change the coding in terminal to change my version of java from 14 to 8 by following along to a website, and when I had completed I double-checked to see if the coding had worked by typing
java -version and it stated I was still on 14. So I attempted redoing the whole coding process over again but when I typed /usr/libexec/java_home -v instead of telling me what java options are available, instead it states "java_home: option requires an argument -- v"
pls anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that message because you have to indicate a Java version number when you use the `-v` flag.

On MacOS, to find all versions of Java installed on your machine, type:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Note capitalization. This argument will show you the path of all JVMs installed on your Mac.

For the lowercase flag, you can see the install path of *specific versions* of Java. For example:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
```

will show you all versions of Java 1.8 installed. You got the error message because you were indeed missing an argument: the Java version number.

Comment: hey! thanks. However, I type java -version to see what my current java version is after I close and reopen the terminal and it still says 14. I'm unsure of what to do?

Comment: Stack Overflow works on a one question : one answer paradigm, and since you got the answer to the question you asked, click the checkmark to the left of the answer to accept the answer. Now, for your second question, you need to update your JAVA_HOME environment variable. If you need to know how to do that, please post a second question and I (or just about anyone else who uses *nix) can help you there.